# swift imageView, collectionView, unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, null

First of all: I know that there are thousands of questions about this subject and for sure in one of them my question is answered. But after hours of searching I did not find an answer which solves my problem...

I have a CollectionViewController (inside a container) and a CollectionViewCell. Inside the Cell there is an imageView. The image of the imageView has to be changed with a button in CollectionViewController.

Here is my code:

```
class essenCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var Bild: UIImageView!
}
```

(The Cell)

```
class essenCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
[...]
@IBAction func xyz(sender: UIButton!) {
//following: the line with the error (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)
essenCell().Bild.image = UIImage(named: "erster")
}
}
```

(The CollectionViewController)

First I thought I could connect the Button to the Cell AND the Controller, this works theoretically but does not work in my specific case.
The image change happens inside an if-Loop (inside my Controller) which refers to the parentViewController. Because I cannot use this reference inside the Cell, I need the button-function to be in the Controller.

*Please* help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the setup for a `collectionViewCell` should be done in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

```
var buttonPressed = false

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("reuseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! essenCell

    if buttonPressed {
        cell.Bild.image = UIImage(named: "erster")
    } else {
        cell.Bild.image = UIImage(named: "placeHolder")

    return cell
}

@IBAction func xyz(sender: UIButton!) {
    buttonPressed = true
    collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This worked really good, thank you. But is there any way to use the `"reloadData()"` part from the `parentViewController`? I already tried `essenViewController().collectionView?.reloadData()` but this does not work. I get the error "_uicollectionview must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter swift_"

Comment: Use a `NSNotificationCenter` notice to send a signal to the `collectionViewController`. This is the easiest way to send signals between VCs IMO.